# Django cannot delete objects and also cannot redirect

Tags: python, django

I'm learning django and run into some issues. I've searched this question already but my situation is not similar to others.

Under my delete view, I have:

```
def student_delete_view(request, my_id):
    #try:
    #    obj = student.objects.get(id=my_id)
    #except student.DoesNotExist:
    #    raise Http404

    obj = get_object_or_404(student, id=my_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        obj.delete()
        print("delete trigered")
        return redirect('home.html')
    context = {
        'object':obj
    }

    return render(request, "student/student_delete.html", context)
```

And here my_id is set in the urls.py as:

```
path('student/<int:my_id>/delete', student_delete_view, name='rmc')
```

I have these in my static HTML:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form action='.' method='POST'>{% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Do you want to delete {{object.id}}?</h1>
    <p>{{object.student_name}}</p>
    <input type='submit' value='yes'><a href='.'>Cancel</a>


</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Thus if I enter /student/1/delete, it will get the corresponding object and ask me if I want to delete it. I could get into the delete page successfully, and it can show the object.student_name correctly which means it does get that object from SQL.

Then If I click on delete, it doesn't delete that object at all and also doesn't follow the redirect function.

Also in the console, it doesn't print out "delete triggered" which means it doesn't trigger the delete at all.

The only thing in the console is:

```
Not Found: /student/1/
```

I have no idea why it tries to go here.

I'm just wondering why it doesn't trigger the delete and redirect is not working.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that url is being accessed via a POST call, and not a GET call?

Comment: @JohnGordon Do you mean the method in HTML is "post"? Yes it is.

Comment: @JohnGordon I've just changed the method in both HTML and views.py to GET. Now it seems can delete the record successful, but it doesn't render the delete page

Comment: Don't change it to GET.  If you do that, then the page will redirect as soon as you load it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At:

```
path('student/<int:my_id>/delete', student_delete_view, name='rmc')
```

Add a / after delete to make it:

```
path('student/<int:my_id>/delete/', student_delete_view, name='rmc')
```

Also change the parameter in redirct to ('home') not HTML